# Backward recurssion

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

There is a task: there is a number of boys who want to fight, if number is even, they divide into pairs and who lost - goes home. And they divide into pairs, fight and someone goes home until they get odd number of people. And when finally odd number of people left - everyone fights with every possible enemy. Formula looks like: n(n-1)/2. For example 5 guys - 10 fights.

If the number of guys from the very beginning is odd - the same way of counting: n(n-1)/2.

I've wrote script that counts all possible number of fights, smth like this:

```js
function qwe(number) {
        if(number % 2) {
            return number = number*(number-1)/2
        } else {
            number = number / 2; 
            return number + qwe(number)
        }
    }
    
console.log(qwe(6));
```

But what to do if I know number of fights and want to know how many people I need for this fightings?
How to execute this function in the opposite way?

Comment: Shouldn't they stop to fight as soon as the first boy loses his fight? Because they become then odd

Comment: Example: 

12 guys / 2
6 pairs fight - 6 winners. 
6 winners fight - 3 winners;
and the last 3 - 3(3/2)/2 = 3 
6 + 3 + 3 = 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot easily reverse this function, at least not entirely.

With three fighters, there will be `3 * (3 - 1) / 2`, or `3` fights.  With four fighters, there will be `2` fights in the first round and then `1` in the second, for `3` fights.  So if we know there are three fights, we don't know if there are three or four fighters.  Similarly, `qwe (10)` is `15` and so is `qwe (16)`.

It's possible -- and in fact it seems likely from my tests (up to `n` of `1000000`) that there are at most two inputs to yield any given output.

We can find them all through exhaustive search, because it's easy to show that `qwe (n)` is always at least `n - 1`, so if we check the answers for all values up to one more than our target, we will have found all those that hit the target.  But with a function as chaotic as this, I have a hard time seeing how to improve that exhaustive search.  We can easily test the odd-number results, since `qwe (n) = n * (n - 1) / 2` and through some simple algebra, we can demonstrate that if `qwe (n) == t`, then `n = (1 + sqrt (1 + 8 * t)) / 2`, but testing the recursive step seems much more problematic.

Comment: Thank you, Scott. Can you help me to understand algorithm of getting this two values? At first we check the difficult stage when there is odd number of fights: 
N * (N-1) / 2 = starData 
N^2 - N - 2*srartData = 0;
and we solve this quadratic equation, and if at least one of our N-s is positive integer, we check this option.  
And what we do next?

Comment: The point of my answer is that there is no clear algorithm except to search the values less than `n`, tracking all those that generate `n`.  For `n` less than a million, I did this, and found a small number that had two answers and many more that had one, and none that had more.  Perhaps someone cleverer than I will point out something I'm missing, but I can't see anything better that.  1/2

Comment: Note that I did solve the quadratic equation there.  If `1 + 8 * t` is a perfect square, then you have a solution in the odd number `(1 + sqrt (1 + 8 * t)) / 2`.  But that solves only for those that started with an odd number of people, not those that cut contestants in half some number of times, then followed the odd option.  2 /2

Comment: If that's interesting for you, I've created new topic with solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69117257/my-test-task-for-trainee-javascript-quadratic-equation-and-game-theory